# How do I use std::unique_ptr<T> with an interface that returns an int?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

I want to wrap the `open`/`close` POSIX API into a RAII-compatible object like `std::unique_ptr`. But the `open` function returns an `int` (i.e. not a `HANDLE`, which is a pointer to `void`), and I'm not sure how I can use the `std::unique_ptr` template class with an `int`. Can somebody please help me?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? If you don't have a pointer to free, `shared_ptr` is of no use.

Comment: Shared pointer is not the right class for that as the returned value is not a pointer. Read [A Proposal to Add additional RAII Wrappers to the Standard Library](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3677.html).

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves Because it's smart and allows you to close the file automatically when nobody else needs it not leaking resources?

Comment: @RedX Sure, it frees pointers, but it doesn't magically guess that a file needs to be closed. As you said, this is not the right class. That's why I was asking why he wanted to specifically use `shared_ptr`.

Comment: Writing a custom RAII class is simple enough to do, although complexity increases if you want to allow moving it into collections. Why not just write one yourself?

Comment: @icabod The problem is I want to copy(-construct) the class objects.

Comment: So implement the Rule of Five for C++11 and you are good.

Comment: The link a posted has an example implementation of exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: @RedX OK... It's just that I am too lazy :-)

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves Note that shared_ptr doesn't have to `delete` what it is holding.  You can supply a custom disposal thing to properly dispose of the pointer.  However, shared_ptr is tied to holding a pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really, all you want is for the close(int fileHandle) to be managed for you, right? Why not create a simple c++ class with a destructor that calls close() for you? I think this is the behavior you are looking for.

std::shared_ptr, and friends only deal with heap pointers created with new, and will call delete ptr, not what you are looking for here.

Edit: Mr. Fernandes makes a good point. shared_ptr<> manages reference counting for you, so using it with a custom deleter for an opaque handle from a c lib call (e.g. file handle) is a very reasonable thing to do, if just a tad tricky for other team members to follow. It also directly answer's OP's question.

Here's an [interesting discussion](http://herbsutter.com/2012/01/20/gotw-103-smart-pointers-part-1-difficulty-310/) on the topic from Herb Sutter's web site.

Comment: Remember that if the file failed to open you should not try to close it in the destructor.

Comment: @Steger The problem is I want to copy(-construct) the class objects.

Comment: @EgorTensin For copying, you can keep a lockCount inside the object, setting it to 1 upon successful open(), incrementing it on each copy, and decrement in the dtor. When it goes to zero, call close(). This is the standard way it's done. Unless you want to open a new file handle for each copy, then you wouldn't need lockCount. Oh yeah, the file handle and lock count would have to be in a new, separate object, so it can be shared amongst multiple PosixFileHandle objects. I have this pattern in several places in my programs. Let me know if this is not clear.

Comment: @EgorTensin Then use a `std::shared_ptr<MyPosixWrapper>`. `MyPosixWrapper` takes care of the allocation and destruction (and doesn't need to be copyable), `std::shared_ptr` takes care of providing the ability to copy-construct it. Each class has one purpose and is simple, but the combination is powerful.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Agreed. But using shared_ptr template with custom deleter may be considered tricky code. I don't know about others, but I expect managed pointers to contain new'd pointers... Just sayin'.

Comment: Are you kidding me? Using shared_ptr with a custom deleter, i.e., something it was built for, is tricky code but reimplementing shared_ptr yourself is not?

Comment: Just saying that any curious coder would want to dig into a piece of code that stores a file handle as a shared pointer. But if you were to use shared_ptr at the top level (with it's built-in copy logic), then new up the PosixFileHandle object as a shared_ptr, you would have a simple solution without even having to redefine the deleter.

Answer (score 1):

It's not guaranteed to work by the standard (the result is implementation-defined), but I'd guess that on most sane implementations, doing a round trip `int -> void* -> int` will give you the same `int` value. So you could do this:

```
std::shared_ptr<void> raii(
  reinterpret_cast<void*>(open(/*...*/),
  [](void *p) { close(reinterpret_cast<int>(p)); }
);
```

This uses a custom deleter which calls `close()`. You might want to wrap this in your own class to present a nicer outside interface while still leveraging `std::shared_ptr`'s implementation with regards to sharing & thread safety.

Comment: The layout of *global pointers* are opaque, but can be cast to and from an integer.  ( N1548 §6.3.2.3 ¶5,¶6 )  ( N3242 §5.2.10 ¶4,¶5; §3.7.4.3 ¶1,¶3 )
The appropriate integer type to cast to and from are specifically provided, but optional.  ( N1548 §7.20.1.4 )

Comment: So, `#ifdef INTPTR_MAX` switch `int` with `intptr_t`.  `#ifndef INTPTR_MAX  #error "This environment is deficient.  :-("`.

Comment: @CharlesLWilcox You need to use `intptr_t` to safely cast a `void*` to an integer and back. If you start with an `int`, the mapping is simply implementation-defined (5.2.10p5).

Comment: Can't you `reinterpret_cast<void*>(static_cast<intptr_t>(open(/*...*/)))`, and `[](void* p){ close(static_cast<int>(reinterpret_cast<intptr_t>(p))); }`?  Or technically, we can't assume `intptr_t` can represent all `int`s?

Comment: @CharlesLWilcox It would still be implementation-defined. The only thing the standard says about integer-pointer casts is that a round trip `void* -> intptr_t -> void*` yields the same value. And, for the "start with integer" case, if the mapping doesn't work without `intptr_t` in the middle, it will not work with it either.

Comment: @Angew not quite. `intptr_t` is not magical. That roundtrips with any integral type that is not smaller than the pointer.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Yes, I know. Technically, it's just any integral type "large enough." But I felt it would just complicate the issue at hand.